# nextjs fetch data not showing in template and how to prevent fetch url calling two times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I can see my my api data from my terminal and it's also calling two time. I also want to display data in my page template. But I don't know where I am doing mistake and any data not showing in my template:

here is my code:

```
export default function Content({ blog }) {
  return (
        <>
          {blog.map((blogs) => {
                  {
                    blogs.blog_title;
                  }
                })}      
                
        </>
  );
}


export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Fetch data from external API

  const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog-api";

  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "<secret>",
  };

  const res = await fetch(url, { headers: headers });
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
  // Pass data to the page via props

  return {
    props: {
      blog: data,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return the value from the `.map` method

```js
export default function Content({ blog }) {
  return (
    <>
      {blog.map((blogs) => <span key={blogs.id}>{blogs.blog_title}</span>)}      
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: getting error `TypeError: blog.map is not a function`

Comment: It means that the `blog` property is not an array. Could you attach the output of the `console.log(data);` to your question?